# Automatic line break with backslash in listings

Tags: symbols, listings, line-breaking

I would like to use listings to format bash commands in such a way that overly long lines are automatically broken with a backslash. I know about the `prebreak` option, but it appears as though it is impossible to pass a literal backslash character to `prebreak`.

I learned from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356837/198044) that I could specify backslashes with `\textbackslash`, but using it produces the following warning message:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmtt/m/n' undefined
(Font) using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead for symbol `textbackslash' on input line 8.
```

While this still allows for document compilation, it looks like the `\textbackslash` somehow avoids being formatted according to the `basicstyle` option. As seen in the below example, listings is perfectly capable of correctly styling backslashes that are manually entered.

Is it possible to make listings automatically break long lines with a backslash that is correctly styled?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
% Automatic line break
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines,breakatwhitespace,prebreak={\textbackslash}]
long string of text to test line breaking for the listings package
\end{lstlisting}

% Manual line break
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines,breakatwhitespace]
long string of text to test line breaking for the \
    listings package
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of output of above latex code, demonstrating the visual difference in backslashes]

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @campa That seems to have worked perfectly. I would mark your comment as the answer, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Well, it's a comment, not an answer `:-)`. But this is a question which pops up every once in a while so there is surely a duplicate somewhere. Alas, I have no time to search for it right now.

Comment: @campa OK, what should I do now? I don't know how to "close" a question without accepting an answer.

Comment: @JAKZero Make your own answer what `campa` suggested...

Comment: @MadyYuvi According to [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), I cannot accept my own answer within 48 hours of creating the question. I guess I'll wait until 48 hours have passed and then I'll try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two answers to my question, both of which allow backslashes to be correctly styled when used for automatic line-breaking with listings:

- campa's [suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570292/automatic-line-break-with-backslash-in-listings#comment1437236_570292) of add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble fixes the styling issue when `\textbackslash` is used for the `prebreak` option.
- An alternative solution was found in [the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356780/198044) that I had linked to in my own question. While this question concerned the return symbol, the example code they provided includes a different method of specifying backslashes with `` \char`\\ ``. It turns out that setting `prebreak` with `` \char`\\ `` results in a correctly styled backslash, without having to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

It was very helpful to learn about `\char`, as I expect that it may be necessary for passing special characters to options in future circumstances. However, for this particular situation and for writing with LaTeX in general, I think I will stick with using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` due to the benefits outlined in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/677/198044).